# Broadcom 4331 card sees wireless networks but can't make a connection

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook

I followed the steps to get the broadcom 4331 card working on ubuntu  11.10.  You know where you dont use ndiswrapper, and you patch the kernel and stuff.

Okay so i did this.  Good news: ubuntu sees my card now!! I can see every wireless network ever and pick whatever one i want. So my card can FIND connections

Bad news: it cant MAKE a connection. Not even to google.  It will sit there for half an hour trying and failing to connect.

I will not however that on bootup this morning i was able to establish a connection for like 3 minutes so maybe theres something in the process of booting up that interferes after it loads?

Sorry this is so long, i just wanted to be thorough.

Comment: Have you tried with a *newer* kernel? like version 3.2?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with a Mac, but my HP Pavilion g6 has a broadcom that behaved like that. Try issuing `sudo wlconfig eth1 power off` and see if that fixes it. If it works, you need to put that in `/etc/init.d/` and `/etc/networks/if-up.d/`.